# Chart.js awkward label gaps before last x-axis label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

For Chart.js, would anyone know of a good way to handle the x-axis label spacing where there can be a large label gab before the last label?   The graphs I'm dealing with have too many x-axis measures to turn on labels for every bar. I know this obviously has something to do with the x-axis label skipping logic where it makes a gap toward then end to get a label on the very last x-axis measure.

How to make graphs with label skipping more visually appealing where there isn't a large/awkward gap before the end?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has been a known [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3277) since September of 2016 and a [pull request](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5891) for this has been merged on December this year (2018).

It works perfectly as you can see in these fiddles by [@sgray](https://github.com/sgray) which are showing the current bug: **/61thywor**, and with the fix: **/9t7bs01j**. (*I can't post the full fiddle URL without posting any code.*)

This is **not yet released but it will be included in the [v2.8](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/milestone/18)** release however there's no probable release date given yet.

For the meantime, you can try this [solution](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5707#issuecomment-444802558) suggested by [@RuchiDhore](https://github.com/RuchiDhore).

> You can try following 2 options:
>
> 1. If your labels are 60, make them 61, in this case the gap wont appear,
>      because after 59th, 60th will be skipped and 61st (the last one) will
>      be shown. But the problem with this solution is when screen size
>      changes, there can be a case where a gap may reappear.. that depends
>      on your project requirements.. This option is not much feasible!
> 2. Draw a gridline at position 59th, its label using a plugin, hide label
>      at 60th position and let the gap between 59th and 60th stay as it is.
>      So in that case, gap will be there, but a one that doesn't look that
>      bad as well as the labels wont overlap at position 59th and 60th.